# Decode and Encode text with openssl in Qt C++

Tags: php, c++, qt, encryption, openssl

I want to create a communication between a C++ application and a PHP page.
I have established a SSL connection, but I also want that the messages are encrypted.
For example, this is the PHP code:

```
$textToEncrypt = "my secret message";
$key = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
$iv =  "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB";
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($textToEncrypt, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, true, $iv);
echo $encrypted;
```

In qt C++ I have:

```
void PHPTest::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QString answer = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
    //Now i have to decrypt "answer", it contains the text encrypted in php.
}
```

My questions are :

1. How can I decrypt in QT/C++ with openssl lib the variable
   "answer"?
2. How can I encrypt in QT/C++ with openssl lib some text ? (I'll decode it in php with the openssl_decrypt)

Comment: If you have an SSL connection, your messages will already be encrypted automatically (unless you do something *really* silly like configure both ends of the connection to accept a null cipher suite). Why do you think you need *another* layer of encryption?

Comment: I imagined that the channel ssl was already pretty sure. Thank you.
Suppose that i have an unencrypted channel, I am curious about how to use the tools of encryption opensll in C ++. Thank you

Comment: A fixed key and IV mean yo have a static security context (i.e., you reuse them). That's bad. PHP's `openssl_encrypt` is also usually wrong. You should probably be using authenticated encryption because it provides *both* confidentiality and authenticity. See [EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your PHP site is protected by SSL and you want to comunicate with it through a Qt application, you haven't to manually encrypt/decrypt anything. The SSL does it for you. Just write your SSL client (look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-securesocketclient-example.html for an example) and make your requests to the server.

Comment: I am curious about how to use the tools of encryption opensll in C ++. Thank you

Comment: Look here for an example: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption